Terms are not types, but could I have Type be a subclass of Term in my OOP / C++ dependent type hierarchy?
Here's the code so far in "Type.h".
#pragma once

#include "Term.h"
#include <string>

class Type
{
public:
    Type() {
        typeName = "Anonymous";
    }
    Type(const std::string& typeName) 
    {
        this->typeName = typeName;
    }
    Type(const Type& source) 
    {
        typeName = source.typeName;
    }
    virtual ~Type();
    virtual std::string toString() const { return typeName;  }

protected:
    std::string typeName;
};

class DependentType : Type
{
public:
    DependentType(const Term& x, const Type& A, const std::string& typeName) : Type(typeName)
    {
        *term = x;
        *type = A;
    }

    virtual Type* operator () (const Term& x) = 0;

    std::string toString() const {
        return Type::toString() + ":" + type->toString() + "→" + "Universe";
    }

protected:
    Term* term;
    Type* type;
};

class PiType : public DependentType
{

};

There's this definition of dependent types on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Formal_definition
But if a dependent type is defined to be loosely a family of types $B : A \to \mathcal{U}$ the universe, then I thought that only terms can go on the LHS of $:$ in $B(x) : \mathcal{U}$.   If not, then I would need several typing judgements which seems bad on the code re-use side of things.  Howe should I code it?
I'm guessing it's safe here to let Type subclass (derive from / inherit) Term as a base class.  Is that right?

Does Type really do what $\mathcal U$ does? If you have const Type& A, can you then write const A& a?

Well let's not confuse "Type" with "C++ type" these are two different things the latter not having dependent typing support (it has some with templates but generally not enough I found out the hard way).

If you intend to distinguish between types and C++ types, what are you trying to achieve? I thought you want to embed DT in C++, and I asked that to try to convince you that it is unlikely to happen, but it seems you are already aware of it. Are you trying to implement a type checker with support for dependent types?

@ice1000 yes to the latter.  But instead of working on my own language on top of C++, C++ for now will host the proofs itself.   Yes, it's probably impossible to do the embedding as C++ typing doesn't have all the features needed.  I'm also interested in Rust, but would have to learn it first.  My final goal is to show a diagram chase brute force search happen on the screen visually.  But I don't want to limit myself to "just R-modules" as that would be wasteful of the code.  I would like the system to be pretty general.

Yes, ideally at least, in a dependently typed theory types are terms, aka types are first-class: which indeed is one of the cool features (or promises) of DTTs.  I say ideally because that in full generality is not easily achievable (indeed at least Coq AFAIK does not have it full-fledged): but others will have to help you with more detailed and more technical explanations.

@JulioDiEgidio I'm having trouble getting on with "what's next?"  any ideas on what is the lowest hanging fruit of type theory that is absolutely necessary, would it be var substitution?

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh maybe try to implement dependent function types (aka pi types)?

@ice1000 I'm guessing I need to do that using inference rules?  The trouble is where can I find the "standard list" for Pi-types?

Found this really good book on DTT: https://carloangiuli.com/courses/b619-sp24/notes.pdf

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh  "[in a dependently typed theory types are terms] in full generality is not easily achievable": besides that I should probably have said in a dependently-typed language, I am now vaguely better remembering that in fact what is not easily achievable is the other way round: that all terms are types... let's hope someone will correct me. :)  Anyway, thanks for that link, I am perusing it.

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh pi types are defined in 2.4.1

@ice1000 thanks!  I have to go through pretty much the whole book though to do my implementation: starting with the various Judgement types.   Thanks for your help

Have been coding from the book.  Here is a sample:
SimplyTypedLambdaCalculus::SimplyTypedLambdaCalculus(const Type* baseType)
{
    auto base_type = IsType(baseType);
    baseTypeIntro = InferenceRule({}, base_type);

    // Doing it like the below has two advantages:
    // 1. Each InferenceRule already makes copies that it owns (on the Heap), so this avoids doubling the heap allocs.
    // 2. Line-by-lines are great for debugging purposes.  To inspect each variable etc.

    auto A_type = IsType(A);
    auto B_type = IsType(B);
    auto AxB = Product(A, B);
    auto AxB_type = IsType(AxB);
    auto AtoB = Function(A, B);
    auto AtoB_type = IsType(AtoB);

    productTypeIntro = InferenceRule({ &A_type, &B_type }, AxB_type);
    functionTypeIntro = InferenceRule({ &A_type, &B_type }, AtoB_type);

    addInferenceRules({ &baseTypeIntro, &productTypeIntro, &functionTypeIntro });
}

The code is private, however.
